# Java true if ends with

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) {
      if(str.length() < 2){
          return false;
      }else if(str.substring(str.length()-2, str.length())).equals("ly){
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;}
}
```

So it was a simple question, return true if ends in "ly".
I tried making this, but i'm getting a few errors. (Under the else, and equals). I've been learning all of these just today. Any help appreciated :D

Comment: Your `String` literal is unterminated. `"ly"`. Also, [`String.endsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) is built in. `return str.endsWith("ly");`

Answer (score 0):

From your version, you just had a couple of typos

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) 
{
    if(str.length() < 2)
        return false;
    else if(str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length()).equals("ly"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However, if I wrote a program to test this, I would write it as such:

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) 
{
    // If string doesn't end with ly, is null, or has a length of zero
    if(str == null || str.length() == 0 || !str.endsWith("ly"))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

What is looks like with brackets (my **preferred** version)

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) 
{
    if(str.length() < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length()).equals("ly"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
/*
^   ^ all the brackets line up, which for me makes readability a breeze
|   | */
```

Another way you will commonly see it formatted (not my preferred way but often times standard in industry, reduces lines in code.):

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) 
{
    if(str.length() < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length()).equals("ly")) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a close reason for typos. You should use it. These questions aren't helpful for anyone.

Comment: This is new to me, I thought your code was written without the { for me to read easier, but when I put it in the ide it worked. How come your code works without writing {return false;} after the if ect. I thought whatever was in the {} was what the computer reads.

Comment: Although, you were wrong on the fact that it was -2, but you wrote -3. After I changed you got it right thanks :D

Comment: The reason you put the `{ }` is if the logical statement has a **block** under it. A **block** is signified as more than one line of code you need to run. However, if you just have one line of code under an `if` statement, you don't need the brackets in java, as it reads the logic statement, then just runs the one line before exiting out of the logic statement. However, this isn't in all languages, but java allows it.

Comment: It is good practice initially to put the `{ }`, however in my opinion you are doing it sloppily. I edited my post to show what I would like it to look like with brackets. Some programmers code differently, but I code for readability, and seeing the brackets lineup for me is easier.